# mysql select between two columns works too slowly

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, between

I have this query:

```
SELECT `country`
FROM `geoip_base`
WHERE 1840344811 BETWEEN `start` AND `stop`
```

It's badly use index (use, but parse big part of table) and work too slowly.
I tried use ORDER BY and LIMIT, but it hasn't helped.

"start <= 1840344811 AND 1840344811 <= stop" works similar.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geoip_base` (
  `start` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `stop` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `inetnum` char(33) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`start`,`stop`),
  UNIQUE KEY `start` (`start`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stop` (`stop`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Table have 57,424 rows.

Explain for query "... BETWEEN START AND STOP ORDER BY START LIMIT 1":
using key `stop` and get 24099 rows.
Without order and limit, mysql doesn't use keys and gets all rows.

Comment: What index(es) do you hav on your table?

Comment: you you have an index covering start and stop? i.e. `index(start, stop)`

Comment: I tried two separate indexes for start,stop and index(start, stop) too

Comment: What does EXPLAIN output for this query? What is the table engine, what are your configuration options of mysql, what does SHOW CREATE TABLE output? What computer are you using?

Comment: what the datatype for start and stop?

Comment: Two **separate** indexes for `start` and `stop` is the best you can go with. Waiting for explains.

Comment: +1 to zerkms: **Two Separate indexes, one for `start` and one for `stop`** is best for this kind of query.

Comment: More: If `start` is `UNIQUE`, no need to have a compound primary key. You can use `start` for `primary key`.

Comment: Look to create, table already have two separate indexes for start and stop. Explain below 'table create'.

Comment: It's possible that two indexes, one for `(country, start)` and one for `(country, stop)` might be better, since you only need `country` to be shown.

Comment: One more question: Do you need `SELECT country` ? Why not `SELECT DISTINCT country` ?

Comment: @mitsky: copy-paste exact EXPLAIN please, also before explain please also perform `OPTIMIZE` + `ANALYZE` for target table

Comment: Just tried one primary index for start. Works similar unique for stop...

Comment: i need not only country, it's just for example. distinct doesn't help. does optimize. explane here: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra 
1 SIMPLE rugeoip_base range PRIMARY PRIMARY 5 NULL 33327 Using where; Using temporary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can improve this query using `SPATIAL` indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE
        geoip_base
ADD     ip_range LineString;

UPDATE  geoip_base
SET     ip_range =
        LineString
                (
                Point(-1, `start`),
                Point(1, `stop`)
                );

ALTER TABLE
        geoip_base
MODIFY  ip_range NOT NULL;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX
        sx_geoip_range ON geoip_base (ip_range);

SELECT  country
FROM    geoip_base
WHERE   MBRContains(ip_range, Point(0, 1840344811)
```

This article may be of interest to you:

- [**Banning IP's**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/04/banning-ips/)

Alternatively, if your ranges do not intersect (and from the nature of the database I except they don't), you can create a `UNIQUE` index on `geoip_base.start` and use this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    geoip_base
WHERE   1840344811 BETWEEN `start` AND `stop`
ORDER BY
        `start` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` conditions, they are important.

This query is similar to this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    geoip_base
WHERE   `start` <= 1840344811
        AND `stop` >= 1840344811
ORDER BY
        `start` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Using `ORDER BY / LIMIT` makes the query to choose descending index scan on `start` which will stop on the first match (i. e. on the range with the `start` closest to the `IP` you enter). The additional filter on stop will just check whether the range contains this `IP`.

Since your ranges do not intersect, either this range or no range at all will contain the `IP` you're after.

Comment: +1 although, there's a typo in your spatial example: "MODIFY  ip_tange NOT NULL" should presumably read "MODIFY  ip_range NOT NULL"

Comment: My stupid... I had check you query with "ORDER BY `start` DESC LIMIT 1;" and its works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While Quassnoi's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744860/1095353 is perfectly fine. The MySQL function (5.7) **MBRContains(g1,g2)** does not suit the full range of the IP's when using the select. MBRContains will contain **[g1,g2[**
not including the g2.

Using **MBRTouches(g1,g2)** allows for both [g1,g2] to be matched. Having IP blocks written inside the database as start and, stop columns would make this function more viable.

On a database table with ~6m rows (AWS  db.m4.xlarge)

```
SELECT *, AsWKT(`ip_range`) AS `ip_range`
FROM `geoip_base` where `start` <= 1046519788 AND `stop` >= 1046519788;
```

~ 2-5 seconds

```
SELECT *, AsWKT(`ip_range`) AS `ip_range`
FROM `geoip_base` where MBRTouches(`ip_range`, Point(0,  INET_ATON('XX.XX.XX.XX')));
```

~ < 0.030 seconds

Source: MBRTouches(g1,g2) - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrtouches

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is off.

You're using decimal but not allowing any zeroes. You immediately spend 5 bytes for storing such a number and simple INT would suffice (4 bytes).

After that, you create compound primary key (5 + 5 bytes) followed by 2 unique constraints (again 5 byte each) effectively making your index file almost the same size as the data file.
That way, no matter what you index is extremely ineffective.

Using LIMIT doesn't force MySQL to use indexes, at least not the way you constructed your query. What will happen is that MySQL will obtain the dataset satisfying the condition and then discard the rows that don't conform to offset - limit.

Also, using MySQL's protected keywords (such as START and STOP) is a bad idea, you should *never* name your columns using protected keywords.

What would be useful is that you create your primary key as it is and don't index the columns separately.
Also, configuring MySQL to use more memory would speed up execution.

For testing purposes I created a table similar to yours, I defined a compound key of `start` and `stop` and used the following query:

```
SELECT `country` FROM table WHERE 1500 BETWEEN `start` AND `stop` AND start >= 1500
```

My table is InnoDB type, I have 100k rows inserted, the query examines 87 rows this way and executes in a few milliseconds, my buffer pool size is 90% of the memory at my test machine. That might give insight into optimizing your query / db instance.

Comment: how many records are examined if you use `50000` as an input (or whatever number is there halfway from the least to the greatest one)?

Comment: I know what you're aiming at :) however my data is such that start and stop differ by a small margin so using 50000 I get 1 row examined. I can try to insert the data in such a way that stop differs from start for a number between 1 and 10k and post the results back.

Comment: what are the `MAX` and `MIN` numbers for `start` and `stop` in your dataset? Also, do the ranges intersect?

Comment: MIN(col_start) = 1, MAX(col_start) = 86940, MIN(col_end) = 1, MAX(col_end) = 105909, ranges don't intersect. Full table scan takes 36 milliseconds, but that's probably due to my hardware, mysql config and small table.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id FROM GEODATA WHERE   start_ip <=(select INET_ATON('113.0.1.63')) AND end_ip >=(select INET_ATON('113.0.1.63'))  ORDER BY start_ip DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

The above example from Michael J.V. will not work:
SELECT `country` FROM table WHERE 1500 BETWEEN `start` AND `stop` AND start >= 1500

BETWEEN start AND stop 
is the same as
start <= 1500 AND end >= 1500

Thus you have start <= 1500 AND start >= 1500 in the same clause. So, only way it will succeed is if start=1500 and therefore the optimizer knows to use the start index.